# I am using Geckofx-22 and i cant print without header and footer

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

[About:config - always_print_silent in geckofx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179716/aboutconfig-always-print-silent-in-geckofx)

like this in c# need to disable header and footer, on print 
eg: remove url , date , page no , date

Comment: StackOverflow is a community that can help you with code problems, but we're not here to write code for you.  Could you please edit your question and add code that you've written to try and solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This will solve

using in html tag "moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint"

Answer (score 0):

```
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_headercenter"] = "";
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_headerleft"] = "";
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_headerright"] = "";
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_edge_top"] = 0;
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_edge_bottom"] = 0;
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_footerright"] = "";
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_footerleft"] = "";
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_footercenter"] = "";
            GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_unwriteable_margin_bottom"] = -1;
```